# How to replace NA with 0 While Querying to SQL from R?

Tags: sql, r

When my program in R needs to take the mean of NA and 0, it returns NA. Is there any way to make it return a 0 when doing this calculation?

```
#average is my connection to SQL
  cars <- average %>%
summarise(mean = mean(REDACTEDCOLNAME),  na.rm = TRUE)
```

I would like cars$mean to return 0 when taking the mean of NA and 0.

Additionally, I would like the program to treat NA as 0.

Comment: You should probably add what you want to happen when NA is combined with another number than zero, or multiple numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I would want the app to treat the NA as a 0 in all situations

Comment: Your brackets are wrong; use -`summarise(mean = mean(REDACTEDCOLNAME,  na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thank you SO much!